# Visual Studio USE LOCAL IIS WEB SERVER issue with IIS 7.5

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-7, iis-7.5

My Visual Studio 2010 issues following error when I try to map application to use local IIS:

[image]

A larger image can be viewed here:

> http://img717.imageshack.us/img717/8323/errorvi.jpg

I run VS2010 as administrator and I have installed (I guess) all necessary services and IIS features.

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Every time when I reinstalled IIS it suddenly started to work. Then, next day issue reoccured. There was an issue with domain group policy, it turned out that some services were getting disabled with PC reset.

Comment: What services did you need to re-enable? I am having a similar battle with our GPO currently.

Comment: Hmm, I can't rightly say. Admin guys did it. But for sure all IIS services were disabled with every system start + Windows Process Activation Service + (as I recall) some kind of authentication service.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated:**

Having looked at the error message again, when you say you run as administrator, are you running as an account that a member of the Administrators group or the real Administrator?

If it's an account that's a **member** of the administrators group then you still need to right click and "Run As Administrator".

Comment: Thx, but I have them all installed.

Comment: I'm local administrator + I've set RUN AS ADMIN option in exe properties, so yes.

Comment: @dragonfly - have you changed anything with your local security policy?